# Repeat & Reset Loop

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, gsap

I was wondering if it is possible to Repeat and Reset a loop. I'm using TweenLite to create a slide animation of 3 images. Each with a delay of 3 second between them.

After 6 seconds I want this loop to repeat itself so I have a slideshow. Any suggestions because so far I have ended up with endless loops causing it to crash.

```
var clips:Array = [image, image2, image3];
var i = 0;

while ( i < 4) {
    var timer = i;
    TweenLite.to(clips[i], 6, {x:300, ease:Linear.easeNone,delay:timer*3});
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loops will run as fast as the program can, synchronously, locking the thread until completed.  That means that anything time based, should not be in a loop (as loops have no concept of time)

I would suggest using the `complete` callback built into TweenLite.

```
//create a var to store which item is current
var curIndex:int = 0;

//animate the current item
next();

function next(delay:Number = 0):void {
    //when the tween is complete, call the 'tweenComplete` function and pass the curIndex as a parameter
    TweenLite.to(clips[curIndex], 2, {x: 300, ease:Linear.easeNone, onComplete: tweenComplete, onCompleteParams: [curIndex], delay: delay);

    //increment the current index, reset to 0 if out of range
    curIndex++;
    if(curIndex >= clips.length){
        curIndex = 0;
    }
}

function tweenComplete(index){
    next(); //animate the next item

    //get the previous item and reset it's x position (now that this new item is in place) 
    index--;

    //if index was 0, get the highest index instead
    if(index < 0) index = clips.length - 1;

    clips[index].x = -300; //whatever your default x value is.
}
```

Comment: Good logic to handle the animations :), but just wondering wouldn't TimeLineLite be better in this case?

Comment: Not really,  added overhead with no real code cost savings (you'll write the same amount of code using TimeLineLite when the animations in the sequence are all the same).     TimeLineLite is great when you have a bunch of completely different animations that you want to string together, or if you want to use the reverse or other fancy features.   It doesn't especially matter though and it's nice to have those fancy features available when needed later (or if you're already using TimelineLite/Max somewhere else in the application)

Comment: Fair point that it does add a bit of overhead with some extra features OP may not use, but was wondering why re-invent the wheel ;) Although, it's always good to write your own logic and make it work. Upvoting :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this answer worked best for me. I was testing out other methods with a timer as you stated about loops I was approaching it the wrong way.

Comment: Great.  Feel free to accept the answer if you feel it's the most appropriate one.   Also consider up-voting any other answers here that you felt were useful or informative on the subject as well.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in a function:

```
function startAnimations():void
{
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        TweenLite.to(clips[i], 6, {x:300, ease:Linear.easeNone, delay:timer*3});
    }
}
```

Then call the function whenever you want to start the animation again:

```
startAnimations();
```

To do so in an interval, use a [`Timer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html)

```
var timer:Tiemr = new Timer(6000); //6000 ms = 6s
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, startAnimations);
timer.start();
```

Which would require a changing the signature of the function to

```
function startAnimations(e:TimerEvent = null):void
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using [TimeLineLite](http://greensock.com/timelinelite-as). It's a fantastic plugin from Greensock to sequence animations and has built in methods for sequencing animations, reversing, pausing, restarting etc.

To achieve what you want you could use something like this (obviously tweak the values/code to your needs):

```
import com.greensock.TimelineLite;
private var timeLine:TimelineLite;
private var clips:Array;

private function animate():void
{
    clips = [image1, image2, image3];
    timeLine = new TimelineLite({onComplete:reset});
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < clips.length; i++)
    {
        timeLine.to(clips[i], 3, {x:400, ease:Linear.easeNone, delay:i*3});
    }
    timeLine.play();
}

protected function reset():void
{
    timeLine.restart(true);
}
```

Notice the `onComplete` method for the TimeLineLite. This will be called when the tweens are completed.

Hope this solves your issue.

**EDIT:** Updated to latest plugin code.

Comment: TimeLineLite/Max is a good way to go too.  I would suggest though, to reduce the redundancy and populate it with a loop like in the original question.    What if `clips` is dynamic in the end, or has 50 items?  Wouldn't want to hard code that.

Comment: the `restart` function built into TimelineMax does save a little bit of code, and I imagine would be useful to the OP - although calling restart may make the animation abruptly go back to the first image.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis Good point Sir :) Updated my code to add items from an Array.

Comment: Yes, it does take the images back to their starting point, I guess thats where reverse() can come into play if needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Using ***TweenMax:*** (i.e. if you can afford a few extra KBs)

```
var clips:Array = [image, image2, image3];
var timeline = new TimelineMax({ repeat: -1 });
timeline.staggerTo(clips, 6, { x: 300, ease: Linear.easeNone }, 3);
```

Comment: This method is interesting, however when I apply this I have an issue with the third image of my array. When it appears, my first image appears aswell.

Comment: Hmm. Curious. It shouldn't do that. Can you show the code how you implemented it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I figured out why it does that. When the first image hits x:300 it gets reset to start over with the stagger function at the same time as image 3. So X should be placed at 600 so that when image 3 hits 300 images 1 gets reset. If that makes any sense? :)